# How to trigger a single logic app for send different emails as per Azure Budget Action Group conditions

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-billing-api, azure-logic-app-standard

I have created an Azure Budget which is mapped to an Action group.
I have created a Logic App to send different emails with different email structures on different budget threshold example 50% , 75% etc.
Not able to understand, How to trigger a single logic app for sending different emails as per Azure Budget Action Group conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the Microsoft article mentioned by [Vijaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20336887/vijaya). What it lacks is you need to convert the **`NotificationThresholdAmount`** object from the incoming JSON data to **integer** as the conditions are going to want it as such for comparison with your defined threshold numbers.

For the same you can use [Compose Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) for converting the incoming **NotificationThresholdAmount** to integer which would come as string.

> The condition i used was something like this
> **`int(body('Parse_JSON')['?']['NotificationThresholdAmount'])`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ans2human your conditions helped me to get the logic app created successfully as per our requirement. :)

Answer (score 0):

In logic app flow, you can use multiple conditions to send different mails based on different budget conditions.

1. Created logic app flow as shown below,
   [image]
2. The body of Http request trigger is in below format,

```
     {
    "schemaId":"AIP Budget Notification",
    "data":{
        "SubscriptionName":"Subscriptiona",
        "SubscriptionId":"JKKLLLLLL",
        "SpendingAmount":"100",
        "BudgetStartDate":"6/1/2018",
        "Budget":"50","Unit":"USD",
        "BudgetCreator":"email@contoso.com",
        "BudgetName":"BudgetName",
        "BudgetType":"Cost",
        "ResourceGroup":"resorceg",
        "NotificationThresholdAmount":"0.8"
        }
    }
```

3. Selecting body of Http request trigger as content in Parse JSON action and given above code in use sample payload to generate schema.
   [image]
4. I am checking condition for NotificationThresholdAmount value from Parse JSON action.
5. If NotificationThresholdAmount is greater than or equal to **0.8** and less than **1**, sending mail to one user with one format.
   [image]
6. Added one parallel condition to check if NotificationThresholdAmount is greater than or equal to **1** and less than **2**, sending mail to another user with different format.
   [image]
7. Mail format received in below format when NotificationThresholdAmount is 0.9
   [image]
   [image]
8. Mail format received in below format when NotificationThresholdAmount is 1.2.
   [image]

[image]
Here is reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/cost-management-budget-scenario#create-an-azure-automation-runbook)